# Why i can't get the results?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, components, frontend

I dont know why I get an error when I change the state of the component. What I am trying to do is to change the state of the component each time I click in the button and call the function actualizarState.

This is the full component:

```
import React from 'react'
```

import '../assets/css/ComponenteBarra.css';
import * as data from '../catalogo.json';

class ComponenteBarra extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.actualizarState = this.actualizarState.bind(this);
        this.state = { albumActual : data[0]  } 
    }

```
actualizarState(e)
{
    var img = e.target.alt;
    var indice = this.indexarAlbumes(img);    
    console.log(indice)
    this.setState
    (
        {
            albumActual : data[indice]
        }   
    );
}


indexarAlbumes(a)
{
    var indice;
    switch(a)
    {
        case 'isthisit' : indice = 0;break;
        case 'roomonfire' : indice =1;break;
        case 'firstimpressionsofearth' : indice = 2;break;
        case 'angles' : indice =3;break;
        case 'comedownmachine' : indice = 4;break;
        case 'futurepresentpast' : indice =5;break;
        case 'thenewabnormal' : indice = 6;break;
        default : indice = 0;
    }
    return indice;
}

render()
{
    return(
    <div id='barra'>

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <td colSpan='7'>
                        <h1 id='tituloDeBarra' > ALBUMES </h1>
                    </td>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/09/The_Strokes_-_Is_This_It_cover.png/220px-The_Strokes_-_Is_This_It_cover.png' alt='isthisit' />
                        </button>
                   </td>

                   <td>
                       <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Room_on_Fire_cover.jpg/220px-Room_on_Fire_cover.jpg' alt='roomonfire' />
                       </button>
                   </td>

                   <td > 
                        <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/0f/FIOEstrokes.jpg/220px-FIOEstrokes.jpg' alt='firstimpressionsofearth' />
                        </button> 
                   </td>

                   <td >
                       <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                                <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d9/Strokes_1.jpg/220px-Strokes_1.jpg' alt='angles' />
                       </button >
                   </td>

                   <td > 
                        <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/91/The_Strokes_-_Comedown_Machine.jpg/220px-The_Strokes_-_Comedown_Machine.jpg' alt='comedownmachine' />
                        </button> 
                   </td>

                   <td >
                       <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                                <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d3/The-Strokes-Future-Present-Past-EP.jpg/220px-The-Strokes-Future-Present-Past-EP.jpg' alt='futurepresentpast' />
                       </button>
                   </td>

                   <td >
                       <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                                <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f8/The_Strokes_-_The_New_Abnormal.png/220px-The_Strokes_-_The_New_Abnormal.png' alt='thenewabnormal' />
                       </button>
                   </td>

                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


            <table id='tableinfo'>
                <thead>
                        <td id='titulotabla' colSpan='2'> INFORMACION DEL ALBUM </td>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda' > Nombre: </td>
                        <td className='celda' > {this.state.albumActual.nombre} 
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda'> Año de Lanzamiento: </td>
                        <td className='celda'> {this.state.albumActual.ano} </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda'> Genero: </td>
                        <td className='celda'>   {this.state.albumActual.genre} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda'> Disquera: </td>
                        <td className='celda'>   {this.state.albumActual.label} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda'> Lugar: </td>
                        <td className='celda'>  {this.state.albumActual.lugar}  </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda'> Portada: </td>
                        <td className='celda'> <img src={this.state.albumActual.portada}  alt='foto' /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda'> Descripcion: </td>
                        <td className='celda'> {this.state.albumActual.descripcion} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td className='celda'> Canciones: </td>
                        <td className='celda'> 
                        <ul>
                                {
                                !this.state.albumActual.canciones
                                    ? null
                                    : this.state.albumActual.canciones.map(e => {
                                    return (
                                        <li>{e.numero}: {e.titulo}</li>
                                    )
                                    })
                                }
                         </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>    
            </table>
    </div>      
    )   
}
```

}
export default ComponenteBarra;

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsgbv.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine to me. I have used dummy data from my side. There could be error in your json file. It is better if you share the error details. Here is the code which is working fine.

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-feather-88iv0)

```
import React from 'react';

const data = [
    {
        ano: 'testing',
        genre: 'working',
        label: 'yes',
        lugar: 'again',
        portada: 'Nugen',
        description: 'testing',
        canciones: [{
            numero: 'numero',
            titulo: 'titulo'
        }]
    },
    {
        ano: 'testing',
        genre: 'working',
        label: 'yes',
        lugar: 'again',
        portada: 'Nugen',
        description: 'testing',
        canciones: []
    },
    {
        ano: 'second',
        genre: 'aho',
        label: 'yes',
        lugar: 'again',
        portada: 'Nugen',
        description: 'testing',
        canciones: []
    },
    {
        ano: 'testing',
        genre: 'working',
        label: 'yes',
        lugar: 'again',
        portada: 'Nugen',
        description: 'testing',
        canciones: []
    },
    {
        ano: 'testing',
        genre: 'working',
        label: 'yes',
        lugar: 'again',
        portada: 'Nugen',
        description: 'testing',
        canciones: []
    },
    {
        ano: 'testing',
        genre: 'working',
        label: 'yes',
        lugar: 'again',
        portada: 'Nugen',
        description: 'testing',
        canciones: []
    }
];
class ComponenteBarra extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.actualizarState = this.actualizarState.bind(this); this.state = { albumActual: data[0] }
    }
    actualizarState(e) {
        debugger;
        var img = e.target.alt;
        var indice = this.indexarAlbumes(img);
        console.log(indice)
        this.setState
            (
                {
                    albumActual: data[indice]
                }
            );
    }


    indexarAlbumes(a) {
        var indice;
        switch (a) {
            case 'isthisit': indice = 0; break;
            case 'roomonfire': indice = 1; break;
            case 'firstimpressionsofearth': indice = 2; break;
            case 'angles': indice = 3; break;
            case 'comedownmachine': indice = 4; break;
            case 'futurepresentpast': indice = 5; break;
            case 'thenewabnormal': indice = 6; break;
            default: indice = 0;
        }
        return indice;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id='barra'>

                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <td colSpan='7'>
                            <h1 id='tituloDeBarra' > ALBUMES </h1>
                        </td>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                                    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/09/The_Strokes_-_Is_This_It_cover.png/220px-The_Strokes_-_Is_This_It_cover.png' alt='isthisit' />
                                </button>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                                    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Room_on_Fire_cover.jpg/220px-Room_on_Fire_cover.jpg' alt='roomonfire' />
                                </button>
                            </td>

                            <td >
                                <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                                    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/0f/FIOEstrokes.jpg/220px-FIOEstrokes.jpg' alt='firstimpressionsofearth' />
                                </button>
                            </td>

                            <td >
                                <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                                    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d9/Strokes_1.jpg/220px-Strokes_1.jpg' alt='angles' />
                                </button >
                            </td>

                            <td >
                                <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                                    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/91/The_Strokes_-_Comedown_Machine.jpg/220px-The_Strokes_-_Comedown_Machine.jpg' alt='comedownmachine' />
                                </button>
                            </td>

                            <td >
                                <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                                    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d3/The-Strokes-Future-Present-Past-EP.jpg/220px-The-Strokes-Future-Present-Past-EP.jpg' alt='futurepresentpast' />
                                </button>
                            </td>

                            <td >
                                <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                                    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f8/The_Strokes_-_The_New_Abnormal.png/220px-The_Strokes_-_The_New_Abnormal.png' alt='thenewabnormal' />
                                </button>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>


                <table id='tableinfo'>
                    <thead>
                        <td id='titulotabla' colSpan='2'> INFORMACION DEL ALBUM </td>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td className='celda' > Nombre: </td>
                            <td className='celda' > {this.state.albumActual.nombre}
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td className='celda'> Año de Lanzamiento: </td>
                            <td className='celda'> {this.state.albumActual.ano} </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td className='celda'> Genero: </td>
                            <td className='celda'>   {this.state.albumActual.genre} </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className='celda'> Disquera: </td>
                            <td className='celda'>   {this.state.albumActual.label} </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className='celda'> Lugar: </td>
                            <td className='celda'>  {this.state.albumActual.lugar}  </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className='celda'> Portada: </td>
                            <td className='celda'> <img src={this.state.albumActual.portada} alt='foto' /> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className='celda'> Descripcion: </td>
                            <td className='celda'> {this.state.albumActual.descripcion} </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className='celda'> Canciones: </td>
                            <td className='celda'>
                                <ul>
                                    {
                                        !this.state.albumActual.canciones
                                            ? null
                                            : this.state.albumActual.canciones.map(e => {
                                                return (
                                                    <li>{e.numero}: {e.titulo}</li>
                                                )
                                            })
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ComponenteBarra;
```

Comment: I added a codesanbox link to this answer as an edit.  @Varun Sharma. Is correct. The code is fine it must be your data.

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-feather-88iv0

Comment: yeah. i ve replaced  my json file content with yours and when i save it i get the following mistake

Comment: i dont know how to add the image in comments. how i do that??